# Jquery upload to preset URL based on filetype

Tags: jquery, upload

I need an upload system which uploads to a specific preset URL based on its filetype, for example:

images will be uploaded to "exampleserver.com/upload/image" and videos will be uploaded to "exampleserver.com/upload/video".

I had a look at http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ but I couldn't manage to modify the code (might be lack of experience in JQuery plugins)

The upload system does need to support multiple file selection and be cross-browser compatible (with the exception of IE6).

Any suggestions or modifications to the code of the Jquery file upload plugin mentioned above are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: the server where images and videos are uploaded to are NOT mine, they are Facebook's.

Comment: What type of server are you running? The destination of your uploaded file will be determined by the server-side http handler such as PHP, ASP .NET, RoR, etc.

Comment: Im running an apache server using PHP, however the files will be uploaded to facebook's server, but for some weird reason you need to upload videos and images to a different GraphAPI-url

Comment: Does facebook have you put the upload control in a <form> tag with additional information to get it to their servers, or do you send it to them some other way? If that is the case, you can use javascript to determine what type of file it is and update whatever hidden form field they want you to send with the file to tell them what to do with it.  Again, not sure if this is the case.

Comment: no facebook has nothing to do with the upload system, its just the end-point where you deliver the files to using their Graph API; its just for the website I'm developing I need a JQuery based upload system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work your client's need to have HTML5 support, File, FileList and Blob. You can see a [demo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) how this works.

Changing the settings in the uploader is quite simple: ([documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) find "Options" )

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'url',
    '/path/to/upload/handler.json'
);
```

I would suggest you submit images and videos to the same locations and make the check on the server side. That will make your life much easier.

Edit:
Here is how you can check the extension and submit images and videos to different scripts:

```
function checkFileExtension(file) {
    var extension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    var image_extensions = ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];
    var video_extensions = ['mp4', 'avi', 'wmv'];
    // The file extension is not in the array
    if ($.inArray(extension, image_extensions) >= 0)
        return "image";
    else if ($.inArray(extension, video_extensions) >= 0)
        return "video";
    else
        return "notAllowed";
}

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // This is triggered when you drag'n'drop a file over the uploader
    drop:  function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            // The file doesn't pass checkFileExtension, return an error
            var extension = checkFileExtension(file);
            if (extension != "image" && extension != "video") {
                // Print an error message in the UI
                file.error = "File extension not allowed!";
            }
        });
    },
    // This is triggered when you click a button and select files from a list.
    change:function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            // The file doesn't pass checkFileExtension, return an error
            var extension = checkFileExtension(file);
            if (extension != "image" && extension != "video") {
                // Print an error message in the UI
                file.error = "File extension not allowed!";
            }
        });
    },
    // This is triggered on every file in the queue when you click "Upload"
    submit: function (e, data) {
        // The file is an image - submit those to
        if (checkFileExtension(data.files[0]) == "image") {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload(
                'option',
                'url',
                '/upload/images'
            );
        }
        // The file is a video.
        else if(checkFileExtension(data.files[0]) == "video"){
            $('#fileupload').fileupload(
                'option',
                'url',
                '/upload/videos'
            );
        }
        // The file is not a video/image - don't submit the file.
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear in the question about this but the upload servers arent mine but facebooks

Comment: Also I need cross-browser support, IE7-9 don't (fully) support HTML5 yet.

Comment: Your only way then is to make the checks on the server-side.

Comment: no it isn't, if you build in a file-extension check and based on that change the upload-url it's possible, I just don't have the knowledge about JQuery plugins to do so

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is the way you may check the extension of the file. Be aware this is not reliable. I may have a `PDF` file and rename it to a `JPG` file and the check will pass.

Comment: How does that code change the upload-URL based on its extension (image/video) ?

Comment: I'm going to try this code and will tell the results tomorrow, Thanks in advance though!

Comment: implementing the script seems to take a lot more time then I thought earlier, though, your answer seems to work for me so thanks!

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the documentation for the file upload component you linked to, it says "Works with any server-side platform" so you're still going to have to implement something on the server side. Here's a couple of links to get started:

easy introduction: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

php manual entry: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear in the question about this but the upload servers arent mine but facebooks

Comment: Right, your ultimate goal is to get the files to facebook's server. Based on what I've seen on this thread, I think you're going to have to send the files to your own server first unless facebook has an interface where you can post the files directly to them.

Comment: Highly doubt thats the only way, It should be possible to have a upload plugin and modify it to check per-file where to upload it to